# Returning object type from ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it ok to have action which returns object type? What implications may it couse?

Thank you

Comment: Controller Action methods must return ActionResult or a subclass of ActionResult. Do you mean the Model type being an object?

Comment: No, I mean action. For example:
if (foo != null)
return File()
else
return RedirectToAction()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC all your controller actions should return types that derive from [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx) which is the base class for all results such as `ViewResult`, `RedirectToRouteResult`, `FileResult`, `JsonResult`, .... So you could perfectly fine have:

```
public ActionResult FooBarBaz()
{
    if (foo)
    {
        return File("foo.txt", "text/plain");
    }
    else if (bar)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("baz");
    }
}
```

Comment: omg, I didn't noticed FileResult derives from ActionResult, thank you

Comment: You've mentioned all controller actions should return ActionResult types. But I tried returning a string from an action and it works

Comment: @Nips, I didn't say that returning a string from a controller action won't work. I only said that it is wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, there is implementation for that if you need to display a value in the _layout view, for example: 
`<span class="navbar-text">Total Registered Users: @Html.Raw(Html.Action("GetTotalRegisteredUsers", "Account"))</span>`
`[AllowAnonymous]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public string GetTotalRegisteredUsers()
        {
            return UserManager.Users.Count().ToString();
        }`
The question is how do I return an object instead of string?